# Build Cascading dropdown from nested JSON of unknown depth with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to dynamically build a cascading dropdown from a nested JSON object which can be of *any depth* but gotten stuck on the implementation.

The JSON from the server looks like this:

```
var data = {
    typ: 'Gren',
    namn: 'Bana',
    items: [{
        typ: 'Disciplin',
        namn: 'Eliminiering',
        items: [{
            typ: 'Klass',
            namn: 'Damer Elit',
            items: []
        }, {
            typ: 'Klass',
            namn: 'Damer Junior',
            items: []
        }]
    }, {
        typ: 'Disciplin',
        namn: 'Poänglopp',
        items: [{
            typ: 'Klass',
            namn: 'Damer Senior',
            items: []
        }, {
            typ: 'Klass',
            namn: 'Flickor 13-14',
            items: []
        }]
    }]
};
```

So the first dropdown should contain two items: `Eliminering` and `Poänglopp`. The second dropdown should contain either: `Damer Elit` and `Damer Junior` if `Elimiering` in the first dropdown is selected. If `Poänglopp` is selected, the second dropdown should contain: `Damer Senior` and `Flickor 13-14`.
And so on.

If the `items` array is empty, there are no sub-categories so no more dropdowns needs to be created. Again: The arrays can be of *any* depth.

Any help/ideas how to implement this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What did you try? Please show us some of your code

Comment: I guess you'd need to use a [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this very easily with recursion.

Here's a rough example.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/voxayi/1/edit?html,js,output)</kbd>

```js
function toggleChildren (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  
  var el = $(this);
  el.children('ul').toggle();
}

function buildNests (obj, parent) {
  var item = $('<li />', {
    text: obj.namn,
    on: {
      click: toggleChildren
    }
  }),
  list = $('<ul />', {
    html: [item]
  });
  
  parent.append(list);
  
  if (obj.items.length > 0) {
    obj.items.forEach(function (e) {
      buildNests(e, item);
    });
  }
}

var data = {
    typ: 'Gren',
    namn: 'Bana',
    items: [{
        typ: 'Disciplin',
        namn: 'Eliminiering',
        items: [{
            typ: 'Klass',
            namn: 'Damer Elit',
            items: []
        }, {
            typ: 'Klass',
            namn: 'Damer Junior',
            items: []
        }]
    }, {
        typ: 'Disciplin',
        namn: 'Poänglopp',
        items: [{
            typ: 'Klass',
            namn: 'Damer Senior',
            items: []
        }, {
            typ: 'Klass',
            namn: 'Flickor 13-14',
            items: []
        }]
    }]
};

buildNests(data, $('#con'));
```

```html
<div id="con"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```